# Keras Weights Averaging

Tags: python, model, keras

I have used two different datasets using Keras to train two instances of the same model and I have saved each weights set under HDF5 format.

How can I average the weights of these two sets (stored in files) in order to create one averaged weights set?

Comment: You can't average weights, what do you expect this to do?

Comment: Weights averaging is common technic in distributed training. You can train the same model on many different machines, with different subsets of the data. But afterwards you have to average all the weights to reach a final model.

Comment: No, I think what you mean is average or accumulate the gradients, you can't just average the weights because they are non-identifiable (they don't have unique values).

Comment: I'm not quite sure i follow you but either way, how can 2 identical models that were created with different data, be merged/averaged?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the average model like this :

```
saved_models = []
for i in range(num_models):
    model = define_model() #your model
    model.load_weights(model_name+"_"+str(i)+".hdf5") #load saved weights
    saved_models.append(model)

saved_weights = [model.get_weights() for model in saved_models]
mean_weights = list()
for weights_list_tuple in zip(*saved_weights): 
    mean_weights.append(
       np.array([np.array(w).mean(axis=0) for w in zip(*weights_list_tuple)]))
mean_model = define_model()
mean_model.set_weights(mean_weights)
```