# GradientTape for variable weighted sum of two Sequential models in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient-descent, tensorflow-federated, gradienttape

Suppose we want to minimize the following equation using gradient descent:

[`min f(alpha * v + (1-alpha)*w)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gTjq.png) with `v` and `w` the model weights and `alpha` the weight, between 0 and 1, for the sum resulting in the combined model `v_bar` or `ū` (here referred to as `m`).

```
alpha = tf.Variable(0.01, name='Alpha', constraint=lambda t: tf.clip_by_value(t, 0, 1))
w_weights = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(w)
v_weights = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(v)
m_weights = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(m)

m_weights_trainable = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, w: alpha*v + (tf.constant(1.0) - alpha)*w, v_weights.trainable, w_weights.trainable)
tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, t: v.assign(t), m_weights.trainable, m_weights_trainable)
```

In the [paper of Adaptive Personalized Federated Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.13461v3.pdf), [formula with update step for alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7Tso.jpg) suggests updating alpha based on the gradients of model `m` applied on a minibatch. I tried it with the watch or without, but it always leads to `No gradients provided for any variable`

```
with tf.GradientTape(watch_accessed_variables=False) as tape:
   tape.watch([alpha])
   outputs_m = m.forward_pass(batch)
grad = tape.gradient(outputs_m.loss, alpha)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [alpha]))
```

Some more information about the initialization of the models:

The `m.forward_pass(batch)` is the default implementation from `tff.learning.Model` (found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/Model#forward_pass)) by creating a model with `tff.learning.from_keras_model` and a `tf.keras.Sequential` model.

```
def model_fn():
   keras_model = create_keras_model()
   return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
     keras_model,
     input_spec = element_spec,
     loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
     metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.MeanSquaredError(),
                tf.keras.metrics.MeanAbsoluteError()],
   )
w = model_fn()
v = model_fn()
m = model_fn()
```

Some more experimenting as suggested below by Zachary Garrett:

It seems that whenever this weighted sum is calculated, and the new weights for the model are assigned, then it loses track of the previous trainable variables of both summed models. Again, it leads to the `No gradients provided for any variable` whenever `optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [alpha]))` is called. All gradients seem to be `None`.

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
   alpha = tf.Variable(0.01, name='Alpha', constraint=lambda t: tf.clip_by_value(t, 0, 1))

   m_weights_t = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda w, v: tf.math.scalar_mul(alpha, v, name=None) + tf.math.scalar_mul(tf.constant(1.0) - alpha, w, name=None),
                                w.trainable,
                                v.trainable)

   m_weights = tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(m)
   tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, t: v.assign(t), m_weights.trainable,
                  m_weights_trainable)

   outputs_m = m.forward_pass(batch)

grad = tape.gradient(outputs_m.loss, alpha)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip([grad], [alpha]))
```

Another edit:
I think I have a strategy to get it working, but it is bad practice as manually setting `trainable_weights` or `_trainable_weights` does not work. Any tips on improving this?

```py
  def do_weighted_combination():

    def _mapper(target_layer, v_layer, w_layer):
      target_layer.kernel = v_layer.kernel * alpha + w_layer.kernel * (1-alpha)
      target_layer.bias = v_layer.bias * alpha + w_layer.bias * (1-alpha)

    tf.nest.map_structure(_mapper, m.layers, v.layers, w.layers)


  with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape: 
    do_weighted_combination()

    predictions = m(x_data)
    loss = m.compiled_loss(y_data, predictions)


  g1 = tape.gradient(loss, v.trainable_weights) # Not None
  g2 = tape.gradient(loss, alpha) # Not None
```

Comment: Could the question we extended to show how `m.forward_pass` is implemented?

Answer (score 0):

For TensorFlow auto-differentiation using `tf.GradientTape`, operations must occur within the `tf.GradientTape` Python context manager so that TensorFlow can "see" them.

Possibly what is happening here is that `alpha` is used outside/before the tape context, when setting the model variables. Then when `m.forwad_pass` is called TensorFlow doesn't see any access to `alpha` and thus can't compute a gradient for it (instead returning `None`).

Moving the

```py
alpha*v + (tf.constant(1.0) - alpha)*w, v_weights.trainable, w_weights.trainable
```

logic inside the `tf.GradientTape` context manager (possibly inside `m.forward_pass`) may be a solution.

Comment: In the documentation of `tff.learning.Model` it states one needs to define the variables during the initialization of the model. So I'll give that a try first, it is probably able to see the variables afterwards.

Comment: It is however not clear how to do this with `tff.learning.from_keras_model`. Looking into the source on GitHub shows that it does not have the option to do this. Does this mean I have to implement a slightly modified version of this `_Keras_Model`, with the other variables included? Or might it be easier to implement a custom `forward_pass`?

Comment: If `w`, `v` and `m` are all `tff.learning.Model` (presumably due to the use of `ModelWeights.from_model`), any chance they are Keras models before that? Using the [Functional Keras Model API](https://keras.io/guides/functional_api/#all-models-are-callable-just-like-layers), its possible to create a combined Keras model from two models first, then use it will `tff.learning.from_keras_model`?

Comment: Your guess is correct. I use indeed `tff.learning.from_keras_model` for the models before I sum the weights. A first look at the documentation of the Functional Keras API, shows mostly the average of the inputs and outputs of layers. I assume there is no real function implemented as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69709168/19087072) seems to provide me what I need in terms of Keras logic? But then with a custom trainable parameter alpha like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64036147/19087072)?

Comment: I added some more information to my question of what I tried regarding your suggestion of the placement of `alpha` and the weighted sum. Is it possible that it loses track of the variables because it somehow calculates the numerical result of this sum in the `tf.nest.map_structure` ? Or might it be because of the assignment of these variables to the new model?

Comment: I would have expected using the `WeightedSum` layer technique in the second post to create a new model that composes both `w` and `v` (replacing `m`) would have worked, was this not succesful?

Comment: I gave it a try but stopped because my goal is not to have the weighted sum of the outputs of the models, but of the internal weights of both models. If I am not mistaken, this is not the same due to the nonlinearity of neural networks? I was also not able to see how I could achieve this with the internal weights. It might be unclear from my question but in fact, I also need `tape.gradient(outputs_m.loss, v.trainable)` to update `v` based on the sum of `v` and `w`. In that scenario, the gradients are all `None` as well.